# How does Spring Data JPA work internally

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I was going through Spring Data JPA Tutorial. 
I am ***confused*** on how does this framework work internally.
Let me state specific scenario

There was specific code

```
/**
 * Custom finder
 */
public List<Location> getLocationByStateName(String name) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Location> locs = entityManager
        .createQuery("select l from Location l where l.state like :state")
        .setParameter("state", name + "%").getResultList(); // note
        return locs;
}
```

This was simply replaced by following interface

```
@Repository
public interface LocationJPARepository extends JpaRepository<Location, Long> {
    List<Location> findByStateLike(String stateName);
}
```

And corresponding test case worked fine

```
@Test
public void testFindWithLike() throws Exception {
   List<Location> locs = locationRepository.getLocationByStateName("New");
   assertEquals(4, locs.size());
}
```

New test case

```
@Test
public void testFindWithLike() throws Exception {
   List<Location> locs = locationJPARepository.findByStateLike("New");
   assertEquals(4, locs.size());
}
```

My question

- How does framework know if i am looking for exact match using = or partial match using SQL like operator (it cant be method name ?)
- if it somehow decide I am looking for partial match then still there are sub options ... like name% or %name or %name% …
- Also how it decides case is important in like ? ( i can have case-insensitive by using SQL like with toUpper() i.e. by comparing everything in upper case )
- *(added ques)* is there a way i can check the EXACT SQL in log some where ??

Hope i was able to explain my question properly. Let me know if i need to add in more clarity.

Comment: I suggest a read of the reference guide, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods). In short it is based on how name your method.

Comment: is there a way i can check the EXACT SQL in log some where ??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I recommend to take a look at [Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) section of the reference guide. It explains the rules pretty clearly.

For instance when you want to find User by first name and ignore case, you would use method name like `findByFirstnameIgnoreCase` which would translate into condition like `UPPER(x.firstame) = UPPER(?1)`.

By default when you have `findByProperty` method, the match is exact, so if you want to have `LIKE` functionality you would use method name `findByFirstnameLike` which would in turn translate into condition `where x.firstname like ?1`.

You can combine these keywords, but it can get a little crazy. Personally I prefer using [`@Query`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html) annotation for more complicated queries to avoid super long repository method names.

Comment: is there a way i can check the EXACT SQL in log some where ??

Comment: @Lav You could use this property (`spring.jpa.show-sql=true`) to enable Hibernate SQL logging. If you use Spring Boot, just put it in application.properties (or YAML or whatever you use)

Comment: Translete how where? What doing spring backside. This just interface, didnt override anything only interface abstact methods. For example when i called findAll() method whats happening? Where is implementation for this interface? Spring using my entity and creating classes? Creating queries? I am confused. I just wanna know what spring doing? There no method body no hibernate codes or jpa.

Comment: @VolkanOkçu check this post on what spring does [behind the scenes](https://calicoder.com/index.php/2018/10/24/how-spring-repositories-work/) to add implementation behind the repository interfaces.

Comment: @Calicoder looks like link is broken. Appreciate if you could fix. Thanks.

Comment: a helpful explanation can be found here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38511337/706589