# How spring data generate sql according to method name?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I know spring data jpa can execute sql by two ways.One is execute sql which is included by @Query, the other is parse method name and generate sql. I clone the source code of spring data jpa from github and want to find how spring data generate sql according to method name.But I can't find the class which is related to parse method name.So,could you tell me something about how spring data jpa works about parsing method name?Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are Spring Data repositories actually implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509882/how-are-spring-data-repositories-actually-implemented)

Answer (score 7):

Its a multi-step process:

1. Spring Data JPA generates a proxy class for the repository interface.
2. The proxy generates a [`PartTree`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/query/parser/PartTree.java) instance for each repository method using the [`PartTreeJpaQuery`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/PartTreeJpaQuery.java) class. The `PartTree` class is part of the Spring Data Commons module, which is a dependency for the store-specific Spring Data modules (like the Spring Data JPA module).
3. The `PartTree` is then passed to a [`JpaQueryCreator`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryCreator.java) to generate a JPA `CriteriaQuery` instance.
4. The `CriteriaQuery` instance is passed to the underlying JPA provider (Hibernate, OpenJPA, EclipseLink, etc.) which then generates SQL to be executed.

Comment: please let me know if there is any documentation available for this.