# Spring JPA in clause throwing Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring JPA for select operation on MySql Database

**Table**

`select id, grp, name from student;`

**Repository method**

`List<Student> findByGrpAndName(String grp, Set<String> name);`

And it's throwing

`java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:127)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)`

I tried to debug the hibernet code to see the query getting created. And query has syntax error.

`select student0_.name as name1_1_, student0_.grp as grp2_1_ from student student0_ where student0_.grp=? and student0_.name=(? , ?);`

It should be `student0_.name in (? , ?);`

Am I missing something to tell JPA it should be an `in clause`

Comment: What is the implementation of the method findByGrpAndName?

Comment: In JPA, repository functions don't need the implementation. It follows some naming convention to detect what those functions are supposed to return. Further read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330369/spring-data-jpa-underlying-mechanism-without-implementation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close! You can use the keyword `In` as a qualifier to the `Name` clause (as described [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)). All you need to do is fix your query to be:

```
List<Student> findByGrpAndNameIn(String grp, Set<String> name);
```

Hope that helps!