# How are custom methods in spring data jpa implemented and executed?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using spring data jpa for my project and i have following pieces of code:

My Repository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface StudentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Student, Long> {

  List<Student> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids);

}
```

and my entity is :

```
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private Long id;

  // other fields
  // getters/setters

}
```

Somewhere in my service class, i have

```
@Autowired
StudentRepository  studentRepository;
```

and then i call findByIdIn from my service layer like :

```
studentRepository.findByIdIn(listOfIds);
```

findByIdIn(listOfIds) method works perfectly fine and everything is working as expected.

I know that the implementation of findByIdIn() method  is provided by spring data jpa.

But i am not able to figure where is its implementation present? 
What exactly is its implementation? 
Are such methods generated at run time depending upon the method-name? If yes  how are they generated and executed dynamically?

Thanks!

Comment: Please go through this post. It might be helpful :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509882/how-are-spring-data-repositories-actually-implemented?rq=1

Comment: This post explains nicely about  the flow when we annotate our additional methods with @ Query. But in this case i have not annotated my method  with @ Query.

Answer (score 0):

You can dig a little bit in the core of the Spring code to see how it works (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository), but basically, it's parsing the interface methods into HQL at the startup time.

You can test just be editing a method name to a field which doesn't exist, and you'll get an error at startup time saying that there is no field as this.