# How and Where was the my repository interface instanced by SimpleJdbcRespository?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I created a custom repository interface that extended by `CrudRepository`.
I just used `@EnableJdbcRepositories` in `StartApplication`.

When I test a method from my custom repository, such as `save(T t)` I seen it be instanced by `SimpleJdbcRespository.class`.

I interested it, I want to know how and where was the `SimpleJdbcRespository` created and have implemented my custom repository interface.

Which line of code should I debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Spring Data JDBC repositories get created by `JdbcRepositoryFactory` which uses `SimpleJdbcRepository` as the implementation for the `CrudRepository` methods.

For additional methods in the repository interface `JdbcQueryLookupStrategy` is consulted which determines how to get the right query for a method to execute in the form of a `RepositoryQuery`.

Currently there is just implementation of that: `JdbcRepositoryQuery`

If something doesn't work as expected with the execution of such a method. `JdbcRepositoryQuery.execute(Object[] objects)` is a good start for debugging.
You probably also want to look up how the `executor` used in there get constructed.

Comment: A general description plus pointers are available via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509882/how-are-spring-data-repositories-actually-implemented/38511337#38511337).