# My logger does not create a RollingFile with Spring (config with logback.xml)

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback, spring-logback

I generate a spring boot project, and I want to log in an external file.

I choose to use Logback implementation, and here is my `logback.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

    <property name="LOG_PATH" value="./logs" />
    
    <appender name="CONSOLE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)]
                %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="SAVE_TO_FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/spring-boot-logger.log</file>
        <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="SAVE_TO_FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I use to log with the classic line of code to log :

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomLogger.class);
```

I know that there is an implementation by default, and suspect my `logback.xml` (which is as the root of the project) is not taking in consideration.

Is there somewhere I have to specify the name of the file, or import it in my application as a resource ?

Comment: That's not how [repositories work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38509882/2541560) and due to generics erasure you can't make them work like that. Follow the documentation and don't try to get clever unless you know how the mechanisms work and can be extended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

I had to put the `logback.xml` in the `main` path of the project.