# Spring Boot JPA Rest Interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

in Spring Boot and JPA there is the interface JpaRepository, which already provides the most important methods like `findAll`, `saveAll`. Is there also such an interface for the associated RestService?

If not, how could one proceed to define such an interface. I have looked into JpaRepository once, there the methods are not coded out. But also only with `List<T> findAll();` specified, where is the actual code?

Thanks a lot

Comment: [Automatically generated](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa#springdatadao)

Comment: It uses combination of reflection and entity to generate the logic on the fly.

Comment: I think you should read this once, you will get the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38511337/7871511

Comment: "Is there also such an interface for the associated RestService?" [Spring-data-rest](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest) is the "topping" which levels (not only Jpa) spring-data-repositories to "rest-services"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the methods are not coded out. But also only with List findAll();
> specified, where is the actual code?

`JpaRepository` is just an interface meaning it provides just the declarations and signatures of what should be available from that interface.

`JpaRepository` is a way from spring to take advantage of `JPA layer` and provide some additional commonly used functionalities very useful to the programmer.

Having said that it is important to understand that `JPA layer` follows `JPA specification`, and is just that, a specification not an implementation. Multiple providers come and provide their implementation as far as they comply with this specification. Those providers (ex `hibernate`, `eclipseLink`, `DataNucleus`) provide the functionality of `JPA layer`. Those providers, provide the code to communicate with database and do the actual work of `jpa layer`.

What `JpaRepository` does, is that it takes advantage of this `JPA layer` and provides some extra functionality by invoking what is necessary on the `jpa layer` and expose some common functionalities. So `JpaRepository` will not communicate directly with database using native queries but instead use the `jpa layer` offered from example from `hibernte` and provide some `jpa query` to hibernate to retrieve what it wants.

Inside Spring you can find some implementation classes of `JpaRepository` like `SimpleJpaRepository.class` but again they don't provide end to end functionality but instead just communicate through `jpa layer` indirectly with a provider like hibernate to provide some commonly used functionality to the programmer.