# How method names in Spring JPA converted to sql queries

Tags: spring-data-jpa

In spring data JPA there are many Supported keywords inside method names
for eg JPQL snippet Distinct  findDistinctByLastnameAndFirstname  translates to

select distinct …​ where x.lastname = ?1 and x.firstname = ?2
In JPA how exactly or where is Spring JPA translating the method names to corresponding sql queries ?

I checked the JPA repository interface and also read Spring JPA doc unable to find how the method name got translated to SQl queries

Comment: just have a look at answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509882/how-are-spring-data-repositories-actually-implemented)

Comment: It explains how a method name is intercepted and processed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

basically it uses criteriaBuilder, you can start in this class JpaQueryCreator

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/spring-data-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryCreator.java